# Using st_read to create an owin in R

Tags: coordinate-system, r, sf

I have updated a program because readShapePoly has been replaced by st_read.
Changing from:

```
unzip(paste(mdir, "AU_Vic_POA_2011.zip", sep = ""))
boundary.shp <- readShapePoly("AU_Vic_Melbourne_POA_2011_boundary-wgs84")
# Create an owin:
boundary.w <- as(as(boundary.shp, "SpatialPolygons"), "owin")
```

To:

```
unzip(paste(mdir, "AU_Vic_POA_2011.zip", sep = ""))
boundary.shp <- st_read("AU_Vic_Melbourne_POA_2011_boundary-wgs84.shp")
# Create an owin:
boundary.w <- as(as(boundary.shp, "SpatialPolygons"), "owin")
```

I now get the error message:

```
Error in as(boundary.shp, "SpatialPolygons") : 
  no method or default for coercing “sf” to “SpatialPolygons”.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: No. `readShapePoly` has not been "replaced by st_read". `readShapePoly` reads shapefiles into "sp" class objects. `st_read` reads shapefiles into "sf" class objects. Spatstat needs its own "owin" class objects so your question is how to convert between these different classes of objects.

Answer (score 3):

With package `sf` use `as_Spatial(your.shp)` instead `as(your.shp,"SpatialPolygons")` and use `as.owin` function from `spatstat` package

```
library(sf)
library(spatstat)

boundary.shp <- st_read("AU_Vic_Melbourne_POA_2011_boundary-wgs84.shp")

# Create an owin:
boundary.w <- as.owin(as_Spatial(boundary.shp))

# or
boundary.w <- as(as_Spatial(boundary.shp),"owin")
```

Comment: I think you need `library(maptools)` to convert SpatialPolygons to owin. As per: https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat/issues/54